# Problema com submit php

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email

Estou recebendo alguns emails em branco, ele apenas vem de um email "MISSING_MAILBOX@syntax_error". Os demais vem todo certinho, com o email do cliente que preenche o formulário

```
define( 'OWNER_EMAIL', 'leads@consorciomenegalli.com.br' );

define( 'DONOTREPLY_EMAIL', 'do-not-reply@consorciomenegalli.com.br' );

define( 'OWNER_NAME', 'Menegalli' );

case 'quote-form':   

        # put the email title here
        $title = 'Nova simulação via website';

        # email headers
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
                   "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n".
                   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n".
                   "From: ". $_POST['clientName'] ." <". $_POST['clientEmail'] .">\n".
                   "Reply-to: ". $_POST['clientName'] ." <". $_POST['clientEmail'] .">\n".
                   "Date: ". date( "r" ). "\n";

        # appointment values
        $values = $_POST['values'];

        # create rows with values from appointment form
        $rows = '';
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $values ); $i++ ) {

            $rows .= '<tr>

                          <td style="width: 200px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 10px;">'. $values[$i]['name'] .'</td>
                          <td style="border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 10px;">'. $values[$i]['value'] .'</td>

                      </tr>';
        }

        # email content
        $content = '<table style="width: 600px; font-size: 11px; border-collapse: collapse;">'. $rows .'</table>';

        # sending an email
        $result = mail(
            OWNER_EMAIL,
            "=?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode( $title ) ."?=",
            $content,
            $headers
        );

        # if the email wasn't send
        if( $result == false ) {

            # second version of email
            mail(
                OWNER_EMAIL,
                "=?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode( EMAIL_TITLE ) ."?=",
                $content
            );
        }

    break;
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Segue um imagem do código-fonte de email que vem sem conteúdo e email que vem com conteúdo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Da esquerda é o que vem sem o conteúdo e o da direita vem com o conteúdo.
O problema parece ser que alguns emails não estão pegando os campos : '. $values[$i]['name'] .' e '. $values[$i]['value'] .'

Answer (score 0):

**O problema ocorre por falta de verificação no conteúdo do email do cliente.**

Quando você utiliza a expressão:

```
"From: ". $_POST['clientName'] ." \n".
```

**Veja que na imagem, do lado esquerdo, o `FROM` e o `REPLY-TO` ficam vazios**. Você está informando que o email vai ser enviado pelo conteúdo contido nas variáveis `$_POST['clientName']` e `$_POST['clientEmail']`. O ideal, nesssa situação, é você validar o conteúdo das mesmas, ou enviar apartir de um email seu (meusite@meudominio.com), o que é mais recomendado (emails do yahoo, por exemplo, teriam dificuldade para chegar no destino).

Eu utilizaria da seguinte maneira:

```php
if (empty($_POST['clientEmail']) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Email não preenchido', 1);
}
# email headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
  "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n".
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n".
  "From: Simulação do Site <leads@consorciomenegalli.com.br>\n".
  "Reply-to: ". $_POST['clientName'] ." <". $_POST['clientEmail'] .">\n".
  "Date: ". date( "r" ). "\n";
```

> Dessa forma, não você não perderá emails nas validações dos servidores de email (yahoo,google,etc...) e ainda esta garantindo que o cliente preencheu a variavel clientEmail.

## Referencias

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Tem emails que chegam com o conteúdo, mas tem alguns que não chegam.